# Set time interval every 2 seconds and stop at 10 seconds for button click

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to automatically click a button every 2 seconds, but i want it to stop at for example 10 seconds. I tried the following, but after the 10 seconds it just continues.

Please could you assist where i am going wrong?

```
// repeat with the interval of 2 seconds
let timerId = setInterval(() => document.getElementById("somebutton").click(), 2000);

// after 10 seconds stop
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId); alert('stop');}, 10000);
```

Comment: it is running with me. 
please show more script of you

Comment: [I can't replicate the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/vu2d8zwb/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this by creating and clearing intervals, one way to accomplish this would be to explicitly perform your action in a loop.

For example:

```js
async function repeat(handler, interval, times) {
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    handler();
    await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, interval));
  }
}

repeat(() => {
  document.getElementById("somebutton").click()
}, 2000, 10 / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, we have a button as shown below.

Then, let's get the button into javascript.

Then let's write the logic for the button is clicked every 2 seconds and after the 10 seconds, setInterval execution stops.

So, let's take a variable timesClicked, which keeps the count of the button is clicked, and increments every time the button is clicked.

Now, since the interval is 2 seconds and the button will be clicked 5 times during 10 seconds, so once the timesClicked value equals 5, we should clear the setInterval function.

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function () {
  console.log("Button Clicked!");
};
// the timesClicked will have the number of times the button is clicked or setInterval is executed
let timesClicked = 0;

let interval = setInterval(function () {
  // after 10 seconds or after 5 times the setInterval should stop executing
  if (timesClicked == 5) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  button.click();
  timesClicked++;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: I tried both methods, and yet my page is in an endless loop. I can see that it does momentarily stop when it needs to, but then just continues to "click" the button.

Comment: Could it be that i am retrieving data from a database using Ajax, that it might be causing it to continuously to loop?